# Difference between XmlDocument.Load(String filename) and XmlDocument.Load(FileStream fs)

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I had tried some code on the adding of new child to an XML file. I noticed the results are different when using XmlDocument.Load(String filename) and XmlDocument.Load(FileStream fs). Below shows the original XML file data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>some text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>another text here</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</grandparent>
```

Below shows the C# code of appending a child element using XmlDocument.Load(String filename)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filename);

XmlNode child= doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "child", null);
XmlNode grandchild = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "grandchild", null);
grandchild.InnerText = "different text here";
child.AppendChild(grandchild);
doc.SelectSingleNode("//grandparent/parent").AppendChild(child);
doc.Save(filename);
```

The result XML file is working fine as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>some text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>another text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>different text here</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</grandparent>
```

However, if I were to use XmlDocument.Load(FileStream fs) as shown below

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fs);

XmlNode child= doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "child", null);
XmlNode grandchild = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "grandchild", null);
grandchild.InnerText = "different text";
child.AppendChild(grandchild);
doc.SelectSingleNode("//grandparent/parent").AppendChild(child);
doc.Save(fs);
fs.Close();
```

The result XML file will be very weird, it is just like duplicating the whole XML file again as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>some text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>another text here</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</grandparent><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>some text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>another text here</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>different text here</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</grandparent>
```

Can someone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you load it from a stream then save it to a file? I don't now much about streams but I think writing to one will append data to the buffer. maybe flush the stream before saving?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso It works fine if I load it from a stream, and save it to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling XmlDocument.Save(FileStream fs) will append the XmlDocument data to the stream.

The XmlDocument.Load(FileStream fs) call earlier, on the same FileStream instance, will cause the position of the FileStream to be offset by the number of bytes in the original xml file. Therefore any appends done on this FileStream instance will be after the data read in. In order to counter act this you need to reset the position of the FileStream.

To reset the position of the FileStream instance use:

```
... FileStream fs ...
... XmlDocument doc ...

fs.SetLength(0); //Optional: Clears the file on disk
fs.Flush(); //Optional: Flushes the stream to write the clear to disk
fs.Position = 0; //Resets the position of the stream
doc.Save(fs); //Save the XmlDocument to the FileStream
```

EDIT: The two FileStream approach. Note, I have changed the FileMode to FileMode.Create before I call XmlDocument.Save; this creates a brand new file (clears the contents of the file)

```
FileStream fs = null;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using (fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    doc.Load(fs);
}

//Do stuff to the xmlDoc

using (fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    doc.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: +1... Closing and reopening the stream may be more readable, but changing position is ok option too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I absolutely agree, and wrapping them in using statements. I would urge the use of two FileStreams. One to read in the XMLDocument, and the other to write it to disk.

Comment: @Xenolightning Thank you so much. You help me understand more on how FileStream really works!